# How to pass variable from other function?

Tags: cron

I want to pass the $job_id variable to the expire_job_featured function (for wp single cron event) but I don't know how can I do that.

This is the full code of setting job's post meta value "featured" to 1 and then I want to schedule a single cron event to make the "featured" meta value to 0 after an hour. But I can't pass the $job_id variable to the expire_job_feature function.

```
    add_action( 'init', function() {
    $job_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'feature_job', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

    if ( null === $job_id ) {
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta( $job_id, 'featured', 1 );
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 3600, 'job_featured_expire' );
    
});

function expire_job_featured($job_id) {
   update_post_meta( $job_id, 'featured', 0 );
}
add_action( 'job_featured_expire','expire_job_featured' );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the problem this solution is trying to solve? ( and why didn't you ask about that instead? I see there are some fundamental misunderstandings here about what functions and filters are, as well as how cron jobs work

Comment: I trying to pass the $job_id to the "expire_job_featured" function... because currently the $job_id is doesn't work in that function. returns nothing

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `wp_schedule_single_event`? Specifically the 3rd argument it takes. Also you should use a taxonomy term not a post meta field if you're going to do a meta query. Searching for the jobs that are featured will become a very expensive and slow query to run if you use a `meta_query`, and it will get progressively slower as the site gets larger very quickly

Comment: Then I need to using like this? `wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 3600, 'job_featured_expire', $job_id );` Well, in this way still didn't change the post's meta value to 0.

Comment: That's not how the 3rd parameter of that function works